# BCFKS creation using cert and key

Tags: bouncycastle, keystore

How can I create BCFKS if I have to store client cert.pem and key.pem in it?

The command I'm using is:

`keytool -import -alias 3 -provider org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider -providerpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.141-2.6.10.5.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/bc-fips-1.0.1.jar -storepass test123 -storetype BCFKS -keystore bcfipsKeyStore-1.bcfks -file cert-kmipclient.der`

but with this I can only store the certificate not it's key. Also this command is hanging in my REDHat machine. It worked few times but most of the time it is hanging and not returning anything.

Comment: How can store key pem alsong with the cert pem into BCFKS. Do I need to do it programatically or using keytool command line. Which way is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for generate different keys and also BCFKS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# Certificates password.
PASS=123456

# Server.
SERVER_DN="CN=localhost,OU=RC,O=RC,L=Los Angelest,S=CA,C=US"

# Client.
CLIENT_DN="CN=www.localhost.com,OU=RC,O=RC,L=Los Angelest,S=CA,C=US"

# Cleanup.
rm -vf node.*
rm -vf client.*
rm -vf wc.*
rm -vf ca.*
rm -vf in*
rm -vf seri*
rm -vf trust*
rm -vf *pem
rm -vf *cnf
rm -vf *conf

# ca key config.
cat << EOF > ca_key.conf
[req]
prompt                 = no
distinguished_name     = dn
req_extensions         = req_ext
[ dn ]
countryName            = US
stateOrProvinceName    = CA
localityName           = Los Angelest
organizationName       = localhost
commonName             = localhost
organizationalUnitName = localhost
emailAddress           = localhost@localhost.com
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName         = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1                  = localhost
EOF

# ca configuration file
cat << EOF > ca.cnf
[ ca ]
default_ca = CertificateAuthority

[ CertificateAuthority ]
certificate = ./ca.pem
database = ./index.txt
private_key = ./ca.key
new_certs_dir = ./
default_md = sha1
policy = policy_match
serial = ./serial
default_days = 365

[policy_match]
commonName = supplied
EOF

# webconsole configuration file
cat << EOF > wc.conf
[req]
prompt                 = no
distinguished_name     = dn
req_extensions         = req_ext
[ dn ]
countryName            = US
stateOrProvinceName    = CA
localityName           = Los Angelest
organizationName       = localhost
commonName             = localhost
organizationalUnitName = localhost
emailAddress           = localhost@localhost.com
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName         = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1                  = localhost
IP.1                   = 127.0.0.1
EOF

touch index.txt
echo 01 > serial

# Generate CA
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -config ca_key.conf -out ca.csr -keyout ca.key
openssl x509 -trustout -signkey ca.key -req -in ca.csr -out ca.pem
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -noprompt  -import -file ca.pem -alias CertificateAuthority -keystore trust.jks

# Generate node certificates
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias node -deststorepass ${PASS} -keystore node.jks -noprompt \
 -dname ${SERVER_DN} \
 -storepass ${PASS} \
 -keypass ${PASS}
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -certreq -alias node -file node.csr -keystore node.jks
openssl ca -batch -config ca.cnf -out node.pem -infiles node.csr
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -import -alias ca -keystore node.jks -file ca.pem -noprompt
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -import -alias node -keystore node.jks -file node.pem -noprompt
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srckeystore node.jks -destkeystore node.p12 -srcstorepass ${PASS} -deststorepass ${PASS} -srcalias node -destalias node -noprompt
openssl pkcs12 -in node.p12 -out ca_odbc.pem -passin pass:${PASS} -nodes

# Generate Client cerificates
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias client -deststorepass ${PASS} -keystore client.jks -noprompt \
 -dname ${CLIENT_DN} \
 -storepass ${PASS} \
 -keypass ${PASS}
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -certreq -alias client -file client.csr -keystore client.jks
openssl ca -batch -config ca.cnf -out client.pem -infiles client.csr
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -import -alias ca -keystore client.jks -file ca.pem -noprompt
keytool -deststorepass ${PASS} -import -alias client -keystore client.jks -file client.pem -noprompt
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srckeystore client.jks -destkeystore client.p12 -srcstorepass ${PASS} -deststorepass ${PASS} -srcalias client -destalias client -noprompt
openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -out client.pem -passin pass:${PASS} -nodes

# Generate web console cerificates
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:${PASS} -out wc.key 1024
openssl req -new -passin pass:${PASS} -key wc.key -config wc.conf -out wc.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in wc.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -extensions req_ext -extfile wc.conf -out wc.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in wc.crt -inkey wc.key -passin pass:${PASS} -certfile wc.crt -out wc.p12 -passout pass:${PASS}
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore wc.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore wc.jks -deststoretype JKS -noprompt -srcstorepass ${PASS} -deststorepass ${PASS}

# Convert java keystore format from jks to bcfks
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore node.jks -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass ${PASS} \
-destkeystore node.bcfks -deststorepass ${PASS} -deststoretype BCFKS -providername BCFIPS \
-provider org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider -providerpath bc-fips-1.0.2.jar
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore trust.jks -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass ${PASS} \
-destkeystore trust.bcfks -deststorepass ${PASS} -deststoretype BCFKS -providername BCFIPS \
-provider org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider -providerpath bc-fips-1.0.2.jar
```